# Make a Form show with a Slide Transition

Tags: ios, forms, delphi, delphi-xe5

For my application, When showing new forms, I would like for there to be a transition slide when they appear somewhat similar to how Tab items can appear with slide transitions - well, actually in the same manner.

I am unable to find any troubleshooting or examples surrounding the specific matter. The only work around I can think of is just using a tab control for all three forms and placing them within the tab control.

I have also tried `Form.animateFloatWait()` function as one would normally do with controls on forms, but to no avail.

How do I get my forms to slide in view?

Comment: It would help to have the code where you tried and failed; I think you're much more likely to get an answer that way. Just paste it in the question, but make sure it' you trim it down to the essentials.

Comment: Oops! Until I saw the ios tag, I almost suggested the less-known but very versatile  animation **VCL** library called [AnyiQuack][1] ;)


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/accessquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With RAD Studio XE5, either Delphi or C++ Builder, the form is fullScreen displayed.

Therefore, if we need to make some effect with slide transition, we need to use TPanel for perfect performance:

1. Add an TPanel, make it as fullsize, and do not use align to do so.
   We need to initalize the position and size of TPanel in FormCreate method.
2. Create second TPanel for the form, not let second TPanel be child of first TPanel.
   Initialize the position and size of the second TPanel, make sure it is placed in the right side of screen.

FormCreate method:

```
procedure TFormMainView.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 newLocation : TPosition;
begin
  newLocation := self.btnLogin.Position;
  newLocation.X := screen.Size.Width - self.btnLogin.Width - 5;
  self.btnLogin.Position := newLocation;

  self.PanelMainView.Position.X := 0;
  self.PanelMainView.Position.Y := 0;
  self.PanelMainView.Width := screen.Size.Width;
  self.PanelMainView.Height := screen.Size.Height;

  self.PanelLogin.Position.X := screen.Size.Width;
  self.PanelLogin.Position.Y := 0;
  self.PanelLogin.Width := screen.Size.Width;
  self.PanelLogin.Height := screen.Size.Height;
end;
```

With Screen.Size, we can make sure the TPanel can fit various size of device, say, Android Phones.
And set a button on first and second view, to toggle the slide animation (button on 1st Panel to toggle
the animation to slide to left, and button on 2nd Panel to toggle the animation to slide to right.)

Let's name the button on 1st Panel as btnLogin, so the method to handle the btnLoginClick event is:
ATTENTION: FloatAnimation1 is for 2nd Panel, FloatAnimation2 is for 1st Panel, and the "Property Name"
of both TFloatAnimation is "Position.X", this will make the animation on the X axis:

```
procedure TFormMainView.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   self.FloatAnimation2.StartValue := 0;
   self.FloatAnimation2.StopValue := -1 * screen.Size.Width;

   self.FloatAnimation1.StartValue := screen.Size.Width;
   self.FloatAnimation1.StopValue := 0;

   self.FloatAnimation2.start;
   self.FloatAnimation1.Start;
end;
```

The button of 2nd Panel named "btnBacktoMainView", and the event handler is:

```
procedure TFormMainView.btnBackToMainScreenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   self.FloatAnimation1.StartValue := self.PanelLogin.Position.X;
   self.FloatAnimation1.StopValue := self.PanelLogin.Position.X + self.PanelLogin.Width;

   self.FloatAnimation2.StartValue := self.PanelMainView.Position.X;
   self.FloatAnimation2.StopValue := self.PanelMainView.Position.X + self.PanelMainView.Width;

   self.FloatAnimation1.Start;
   self.FloatAnimation2.Start;
end;
```

See? what we did is to set the "statValue", "StopValue" of animation object, and invoke the start method,
the Panel slide so great.

Maybe this way is not the best way to make view transition, but it works, and perform perfect.
I used to use similar way to handle more than one view in Win32 application in this 10 years,
and the effect is good.

The only difference is that I have to use TTimer and Application.ProcessMessage to make sure the
animation in Win32 work. (Form project, of course).

And I tested this way in XE5 for either iOS or Android, and work in either platform. Share with
everybody.

Comment: Plus, this solution could be used in Android also!

Comment: Used a TLayout to host all controls. As a child component of the 'Main screen' TLayout, I also used a TPanel. Gave the TPanel a background color, and a TShadowEffect. Lastly, I sent the TPanel control to the back of all other controls. I then created the animation for the TLayout. Works Perfectly! Reason why I didn't use a TPanel in place of the TLayout was because ListBoxes inside of the TPanel experienced major lagg when scrolling.

Comment: @DenniesChang can you put a complete code for this solution!? im really confounded!!

Answer (score -1):

You might just try brute force. 
IE. A for-loop that resizes a panel until it fills the required area.
I haven't worked very much with animated controls, but I've played around a bit with VCL controls from TMS software (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothtilelist.asp). They might have something you could use.

Comment: This question is concerning iOS, which means it's FMX and not VCL. VCL is Windows-only.