# Delphi XE5 form transition

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a mobile solution in Delphi XE5.
I have several forms.
Is there a way to perform any transition when loading/showing a completely new form from existing form in Delphi XE5?

Comment: Could you elaborate, it just did not get your desired result.

Comment: On iphone, when you move from one page to the other, there is a slide tansition. I have a few forms in my project. I want to move from one to the other with slide transition.
For example, login page, when clicking login you are moved to the main page. The login page is one form and the main page is different form. How do I slide to the home page from the login page?

Answer (score -1):

Refer to : [Make a Form show with a Slide Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056814/make-a-form-show-with-a-slide-transition)
for possible duplicate question.

To answer, I don't believe there is a way in XE5 to make new forms show with a Slide Transition or with some other effect. You have two routes essentially... 1) Use one form and implement a TTabControl. Use different tabs for different displays and use the TTabControl.setActiveTab to change between 'forms' with a transition.... Or use TLayouts to act as 'forms' all within one form.. Use TFloatAnimations to hide/show/slide/appear the TLayouts.

Answer (score -1):

FireMonkey allows only for one form per application on mobile ... you can replace it with TTabControl or invisible TLayouts. There is animation class in XE5 to make some kind of transition.